# must implement the inherited pure virtual method of motherclass

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, virtual-functions

following problem:
I got a abstract motherclass, two subclasses and a class, which uses functions of the sub classes.

**motherclass:**

Vektor.h

```
class Vektor {
public:
    Vektor();
    virtual bool range() const = 0;
    virtual ~Vektor();
};
```

subclasses:

Absolutvektor.h

```
class Absolutvektor: public Vektor {
public:
    Absolutvektor(int x, int y);
    int x;
    int y;
    virtual ~Absolutvektor();
    virtual bool range (int x, int y);
};
```

Einheitsvektor.h

```
class Einheitsvektor : public Vektor {
public:
    Einheitsvektor(int x, int y, int richtung);
    int x;
    int y;
    int richtung;
    virtual ~Einheitsvektor();

    virtual bool Einheitsvektor::range (int richtung);

};
```

**"normal class":** schiff.h

```
#pragma once
#include <Einheitsvektor.h>
#include <Absolutvektor.h>

class Schiff {
    public:
        Schiff(int schiffId, int schiffLaenge, Absolutvektor absolutvektor, Einheitsvektor einheitsvektor, bool segmentestati[]);
        int schiffId;
        int schiffLaenge;
        Absolutvektor absolutvektor;
        Einheitsvektor einheitsvektor;
        bool segmentestati[] = false;
        // c++ vektor
};
```

Schiff.cpp:

```
#include "Schiff.h"

Schiff::Schiff(int schiffId, int schiffLaenge, Absolutvektor absolutvektor, Einheitsvektor einheitsvektor, bool segmentestati[]){
    this -> schiffId = schiffId;
    this -> schiffLaenge = schiffLaenge;
}
```

Soo now I am getting following Error in the Schiff Files:

> The type 'Einheitsvektor' must implement the inherited pure virtual
>   method 'Vektor::range'

The error appears six times, twice in the Schiff.cpp and four times in Schiff.h

I don't know why to implement the function for "Vektor" because this is a abstract class, and I have two different use cases for the function range.

Comment: The signatures on your virtual functions need to match the signatures on your implementations.

Comment: `bool range ();` and `bool range (int richtung);` are not the same function. You probably thought you are overriding `Vektor::range` in `Einheitsvektor::range`, but C++ does not. If you mean to override a function use the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In `Einheitsvektor` you need to declare the method `range` as it is in the mother class ( `Vektor` ). So it should look like this: `bool range(){ ... }`, not like `bool range (int richtung)`. If you want it to have a parameter, you must either declare one more method which accepts a paramter in your base class, or modify the current one so it has a parameter like this: `virtual bool range(int richtung) const = 0;`. You will have to do the same for `virtual bool range (int x, int y);` (in this case the only option is to declare the second range method, with two parameter, so you will have a range method which accepts one paramater and one which accepts 2) .

```
class Vektor {
public:
    Vektor();
    virtual bool range(int richtung) = 0 ;
    virtual bool range (int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual ~Vektor();
};
```

Comment: I ve also tried to  
`class Absolutvektor: public Vektor {
public:
 Absolutvektor(int x, int y);
 int x;
 int y;
 virtual ~Absolutvektor();

 virtual bool Vektor::range (int x, int y);
};` because the error says that I have to inheritaed the methode Vektor::blabla